# grep a file and print only n'th word in the line

Tags: linux, shell

Content of file "test":

```
[]# 0-CPU4    8.9%,   9336/832, 0x5ffe9b88--0x5ffec000
[]# 0-CPU0    13.5%, aa: 4/3, xvl: 35
[]# 0-CPU1    8.6%, SM: 1/4, ovl: 60
[]# 0-CPU0    38.8%, SM: 1/4, ovl: 62
```

form this file, I want the percentage of *last* CPU0, which is `38` (ignoring decimal point)

I use below shell command which works fine, like to know if there is a better way.

```
grep CPU0 test | tail -1 | awk '/0-CPU0/ {print $3}' | sed 's/\..*//'
#above command prints "38"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your data was in a file called test:

```
cat test | grep CPU0 | tail -1 | awk '{ printf("%d", $3) }'

grep CPU0 test | tail -1 | awk '{ printf("%d", $3) }' - condensed

awk ' /CPU0/ {a=$3} END{ printf("%d", a) }' test - more condensed
```

What it does:

- cat will output all lines in test file
- grep CPU0 will only output those lines that contain CPU0
- tail -1 will give the last line from grep's output
- awk will split `[]# 0-CPU0    38.8%, SM: 1/4, ovl: 62` by space(s)
- first item is `[]#`, second is 0-CPU0, third is 38.8%
- awk's printf `%d` will give you just 38

Comment: tried first command (cat...) it didn't print any output, problem with printf?

Comment: try `cat test | grep CPU0`. Do you get any output? If yes, append ` | tail -1`. All good so far? If yes, append `awk '{print $3}'`. Do you see 38.8%?

Comment: yes, `awk '{print $3}'` works, but `awk '{ printf("%d", $3) }'` is not working

Comment: What's the output of `awk -V` and `uname -a`? Also, can you check to see if the output appears right before your command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '/CPU0/{last=$3} END{sub(/[.].*/,"",last); print last}' test
38
```

#### How is works

- `/CPU0/{last=$3}`

  Every time we reach a line that contains `CPU0`, we assign the third field to the variable `last`.
- `END{sub(/[.].*/,"",last); print last}`

  At the end of the file, however many times `CPU0` appeared in the file, `last` contains the value for the last of the `CPU0` lines.  The `sub` command removes the decimal point and everything after it.  Then, we print `last`.